# Open wordpress page in directory the way index.html would open

Tags: redirect, htaccess, directory

I have a directory /mydir.  If I put an index.html in there, it will open when someone browses to example.com/mydir, and their browser shows only the path, not index.html.

How can I get the same behavior, but opening a Wordpress page instead?  I can put an .htaccess file there with `DirectoryIndex`, but that seems to only point to files, not Wordpress pages.

Alternatively, I could use

```
RedirectMatch "^/mydir/?$" "/mydir/some-wordpress-page/"
```

but then the page slug would show.  (The page in question is a custom post type that has has "mydir/" as part of the base URL.)  I basically want, in this directory, the desired page to work like the Wordpress home page.

Comment: Why do you need to create a physical directory?

Comment: are you trying to reinvent subdirectory multisites? What problem does this solve for you?

Comment: I'd never heard of subdirectory multisites, but I guess the term might apply.  This directory is for an organization whose website I am hosting with mine.  They don't have the wherewithal to manage a complete website and Wordpress, and I don't want to manage two installations.  They have always used html files (and a lot of older ones will remain so), but I'm helping them to learn writing in Wordpress.